# With ARC, are static const array's values automatically assigned nil?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Under ARC, I know that "Stack Variables Are Initialized with nil" ([docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-%20TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)). What about static const array's values? That would make sense, but I couldn't find something official stating it. For example:

```
static NSString * const strings[5] = {
    [2] = @"value2",
    [4] = @"value3",
};
```

Will `strings[3]` == `nil`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regardless of ARC, by the definition of the C language, static variables are assigned NULL/nil/0.

Comment: That makes complete sense. Thanks bbum.